# stack overflow when compiling scala code in maven due to duplicate names

Tags: scala, maven, stack-overflow

I need to make some changes to a class in my package but I did not want to loose the initial class. I copy the class and paste it in the same project and changes name of all functions and classes however when I try to compile the package with the new class in maven, I get stack overflow exception. here is the error message:

```
 [INFO]
 [INFO]   last tree to typer: TypeTree(class CustomerMiddleCombo)
 [INFO]               symbol: class CustomerMiddleCombo in package      churnstory (fl ags: )
 [INFO]    symbol definition: class CustomerMiddleCombo extends Serializable
 [INFO]                  tpe: com.cloudera.sa.bell.churnstory.CustomerMiddleCombo

 [INFO]        symbol owners: class CustomerMiddleCombo -> package churnstory
 [INFO]       context owners: method apply -> anonymous class $anonfun -> method generatedComboCountMore -> object ComboCounterJobM5 -> package churnstory
 [INFO]
 [INFO] == Enclosing template or block ==
 [INFO]
 [INFO] Apply( // val custId(): String in class UserAndSingleSeqCounts
 [INFO]   "r"."custId" // val custId(): String in class       UserAndSingleSeqCounts
 [INFO]   Nil
 [INFO] )
 [INFO]
 [INFO] == Expanded type of tree ==
 [INFO]
 [INFO] TypeRef(TypeSymbol(class CustomerMiddleCombo extends Serializable))
 [INFO]
 [ERROR] uncaught exception during compilation: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 [ERROR] error: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I thing there should be a problem with having class or objects or maybe functions with the same name in Scala package, however I have changed all the names in the new class. if I get rid of this new class(which does not have any new line) I can compile the package without any problem!
Can anyone help me with this problem?

here is the part of code that throws the exception:

```
comboCountsRDD.map(r => {
  val sortedOrderedCounts2 = r.origOrderedCounts.sortedCounts
  r.custId + "," + //CustID
    dateFormat.format(currentDate) + "," + //generated_record_dt
    dateFormat.format(new Date(r.timeOfRootEvent)) + "," + //z
    r.origOrderedCounts.seq + "," + //orig_order_seq
    r.origOrderedCounts.totalCount + "," + //orig_order_total_count
    convertMillisecondsToDays(r.origOrderedCounts.minTimeFromRootEvent) + "," + //orig_order_min_time_from_root
    convertMillisecondsToDays(r.origOrderedCounts.totalTimeFromRootEvent / r.origOrderedCounts.totalCount.toDouble) + "," + //orig_order_avg_time_from_root
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAWeek + "," + //orig_order_with_in_week_of_root
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAMonth + "," + //orig_order_with_in_month_of_root
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAQrt + "," + //orig_order_with_in_qrt_of_root
    convertMillisecondsToDays(r.origOrderedCounts.minTimeOverLifeOfSeq) + "," + //orig_order_min_seq_time
    convertMillisecondsToDays(r.origOrderedCounts.totalTimeOverLifeOfSeq / r.origOrderedCounts.totalCount.toDouble) + "," + //orig_order_avg_seq_time
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAWeek + "," + //orig_order_with_in_week_over_seq
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAMonth + "," + //orig_order_with_in_month_over_seq
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAQrt + "," + //orig_order_with_in_qrt_over_seq
    convertMillisecondsToDays(r.origOrderedCounts.minTimeFromNow) + "," + //orig_order_min_time_from_now
    convertMillisecondsToDays(r.origOrderedCounts.totalTimeFromNow / r.origOrderedCounts.totalCount.toDouble) + "," + //orig_order_avg_time_from_now
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeFromNowWithInAWeek + "," + //orig_order_with_in_week_of_now
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeFromNowWithInAMonth + "," + //orig_order_with_in_month_of_now
    r.origOrderedCounts.countOfTimeFromNowWithInAQrt+","+
    sortedOrderedCounts2.seq + "," + //sort_order_seq
    sortedOrderedCounts2.totalCount + "," + //sorted_order_total_count
    convertMillisecondsToDays(sortedOrderedCounts2.minTimeFromRootEvent) + "," + //sorted_order_min_time_from_root
    //convertMillisecondsToDays(sortedOrderedCounts2.totalTimeFromRootEvent / sortedOrderedCounts2.totalCount.toDouble) + "," + //sorted_order_avg_time_from_root-->exception
    sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAWeek + "," + //sorted_order_with_in_week_of_root
    sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAMonth + "," + //sorted_order_with_in_month_of_root
    sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAQrt + "," + //sorted_order_with_in_qrt_of_root
    //convertMillisecondsToDays(sortedOrderedCounts2.minTimeOverLifeOfSeq) + "," + //sorted_order_min_seq_time-->exception
    //convertMillisecondsToDays(sortedOrderedCounts2.totalTimeOverLifeOfSeq / sortedOrderedCounts2.totalCount.toDouble) + "," + //sorted_order_avg_seq_time-->exception
    sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAWeek + "," + //sorted_order_with_in_week_over_seq
    sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAMonth + "," + //sorted_order_with_in_month_over_seq
    sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAQrt + "," + //sorted_order_with_in_qrt_over_seq
    //convertMillisecondsToDays(sortedOrderedCounts2.minTimeFromNow) + ","  //sorted_order_min_time_from_now-->exception
    //convertMillisecondsToDays(sortedOrderedCounts2.totalTimeFromNow / sortedOrderedCounts2.totalCount.toDouble) + ","// + //sorted_order_avg_time_from_now -->exception
    //sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeFromNowWithInAWeek + "," //+ //sorted_order_with_in_week_of_now-->exception
    //sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeFromNowWithInAMonth + ","// + //sorted_order_with_in_month_of_now-->exception
    sortedOrderedCounts2.countOfTimeFromNowWithInAQrt //orig_order_with_in_qrt_of_now*/
}).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```

I test the code line by line, lines that I comment out and exception in the end of them are causing me a problem.
comboCountsRDD type  is UserAndSingleSeqCounts:

```
  class UserAndSingleSeqCounts(val custId: String,val timeOfRootEvent: Long, val origOrderedCounts: TotalCountsAndSubCounts)      extends Serializable {}
```

and origOrderedCounts has a nested structure like this:

```
      class TotalCountsAndSubCounts(var seq: String,
                            var totalCount: Long,
                            var minTimeFromRootEvent: Long,
                            var totalTimeFromRootEvent: Long,
                            var countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAWeek: Int,
                            var countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAMonth: Int,
                            var countOfTimeFromRootEventWithInAQrt: Int,
                            var minTimeOverLifeOfSeq: Long,
                            var totalTimeOverLifeOfSeq: Long,
                            var countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAWeek: Int,
                            var countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAMonth: Int,
                            var countOfTimeOverLifeOfSeqWithInAQrt: Int,
                            var minTimeFromNow: Long,
                            var totalTimeFromNow: Long,
                            var countOfTimeFromNowWithInAWeek: Int,
                            var countOfTimeFromNowWithInAMonth: Int,
                            var countOfTimeFromNowWithInAQrt: Int,
                            var countOfDifferentOrders: Int,
                            var sortedCounts: TotalCountsAndSubCounts) extends Serializable
```

I am very confused: why requesting some and not all attributes from sortedOrderedCounts2 cause an exception in the compile time!

Comment: My eyes! They bleed. Seriously, though,  I don't see any error in that "error message". It looks like a partial part of some trace output from the compiler. Can you post the complete error text in case there's a real error in there?

Comment: @Erin Have you tried cleaning the project before compiling?

Comment: @gabor:yes I did!  I just gave up on finding what was causing the issue and rewrote the logic

Comment: @paul: there was a stack over flow exception while compiling, maybe I copy the wrong part though.

Comment: OK., so is there any point in keeping this question?

Comment: I was gonna close the thread! but I encounter the same problem and now I know more about where I am getting the exception. I just updated the post, does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?